# How use react-router in MUI <tab>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I create vertical sidebar with MUI's  but I can't change URLs with ROUTE
I do that but it dosen't work
please tell me what should I do?

I used to link as a component in tab but didn't work

```
const SidebarInfo = ({handleChange,value}) => {
  function tabProps(index) {
    return {
      id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
      "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
  }
  return (
   ...
          <Link to='/amar'>
          <Tab
            label="آمار"
            icon={<EqualizerRounded sx={{ color: purple["400"] }} />}
            iconPosition="start"
            {...tabProps(1)}
            sx={{
              mt: 2,
              "&.MuiTab-root": {
                minHeight: 40,
              },
            }}
          
          />
          </Link>
```

I tried up code but it dosen't work

Comment: Did you checkout the docs? https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You can find a working example here https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/#tabs